# IC to cut off signal lines

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I am currently working on a project with a central controller which is always powered and a secondary which will be turned off if not needed to save power.

Now I wonder how to make sure, that there is never power on the signal lines which could power the secondary IC via the clamps.

I remember seeing some component, which allowed bidirectional transfer of data but would "break" the connection if the "ENABLE" input was low. Do you know what the name of this component is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some options. For example, the [MC74AC245](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC74AC245-D.PDF) does what your looking for—allows for bidirectional signal flow and have tri-state outputs. You need to drive the output enable line appropriately.

[image]

If this were more of a design question, let's say you want to do this with discrete parts, you could use two tri-state buffers (the one that have an enable line) and connect them up as follows:

[image]

[Bidirectional buffer](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/bus-transceiver.html)

Let's say your main controller is on the 'A' side and your secondary controller is on the 'B' side. You can easily control direction for the signal by driving the EN line either high or low.

Now if you don't want to power the secondary device through the signal lines when it's supposed to be off, you just drive the EN line such that the path from A-->B is disabled. The path from B-->A would still be enabled, if you were to use the above configuration. However, since the secondary controller has its power source shut off, the B side is essentially in Hi-Z mode so it shouldn't have any effect on what you see on the A side.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the explaination.

Answer (score 0):

The device you might be referring to is called an analog multiplexer.